# Dask Worker can't find module on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, dask

So I have a distributed setup of dask with a scheduler running on one container and worker running on another. I have a similar setup on AWS, where the scheduler is running on an EC2 instance and the worker is on a docker container in another EC2 machine.

I want a python file to be available to the worker. I don't want to install this as a dependency directly to the worker as of yet but want to manually copy this file to the worker such that it's available in the python environment that the worker uses. To achieve this, I am add this to the DOCKERFILE:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM daskdev/dask:2020.12.0

WORKDIR /src/
COPY ./python_file.py /src/python_file.py
```

Basically I want the dask worker to be able to run a method inside `python_file.py`. So I submit the method like:

```
client.submit(python_file.some_method, arg1, arg2)
```

This works fine on my local setup of dask and the worker is able to deserialize this call and run the method. Somehow this doesn't work on the AWS setup. The worker keeps complaining:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_file'
```

To debug:

- I logged into the EC2 machine and I see that the container is alive.
- I entered the container and I see that the file also exists where I want it to (exactly like my local).
- I ran python and tried importing the module and that works too.
- I ran `pickle.loads(b'\x80\x04\x95#\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\python_file\x94\x8c\x0esome_method\x94\x93\x94.') and that returns the desired method.

If all this works, what else could be the reason that the worker still complains of the module not existing? Has anybody else faced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This *sounds* like a PYTHONPATH issue - on your local machine the python file is probably present in the current working directory (which is on your PYTHONPATH).  Can you confirm that `src` is on your PYTHONPATH?  If not, I would add that as an ENV in your docker image.

Comment: If it was a PYTHONPATH issue, how would it work when I tried importing the module in python inside the container?